# Show a Dialog Fragment using Kotlin

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, android-fragments, android-timepicker

I have created a code to show a time picker dialog, I used this [Android API Code](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs#ShowingADialog), But As in it, the code doesn't work Because I couldn't call the **supportFragmentManager**.Here is my Code as follow,

**AddToDoFragment.kt**

```
import android.os.Bundle
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import androidx.navigation.findNavController
import com.dsgimhana.todoapp.databinding.FragmentAddToDoBinding

class AddToDoFragment : Fragment() {
    private var _binding: FragmentAddToDoBinding? = null

    private val binding get() = _binding!!

    override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
        _binding = FragmentAddToDoBinding.inflate(inflater,container,false)
        binding.saveToDoBtn.setOnClickListener{view->
            view.findNavController().navigate(R.id.action_addToDoFragment_to_toDoListFragment)
        }
        binding.timePicker.setOnClickListener{view->
            val timePicker = TimePickerFragment()
            timePicker.show(supportFragmentManager,"time_picker")
        }
        return binding.root


    }

    override fun onDestroyView() {
        super.onDestroyView()
        _binding = null
    }
}
```

**TimePickerFragment.kt**

```
import android.app.Dialog
import android.app.TimePickerDialog
import android.os.Bundle
import android.text.format.DateFormat
import android.widget.TimePicker
import androidx.fragment.app.DialogFragment
import java.util.*

class TimePickerFragment : DialogFragment(), TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener {

    override fun onCreateDialog(savedInstanceState: Bundle?): Dialog {
        // Use the current time as the default values for the picker
        val c = Calendar.getInstance()
        val hour = c.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY)
        val minute = c.get(Calendar.MINUTE)

        // Create a new instance of TimePickerDialog and return it
        return TimePickerDialog(activity, this, hour, minute, DateFormat.is24HourFormat(activity))
    }

    override fun onTimeSet(view: TimePicker?, hourOfDay: Int, minute: Int) {
        TODO("Not yet implemented")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're in a `Fragment`, not an `Activity`

> You can get the `FragmentManager` by calling `getSupportFragmentManager()` from the `FragmentActivity` or `getFragmentManager()` from a `Fragment`.

so you need `getFragmentManager()` (or just `fragmentManager` in Kotlin) - or `parentFragmentManager` if you want, the former's deprecated and tells you to use this instead

Answer (score 1):

Please try,

```
val transaction = supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction()
timePicker.show(transaction,"time_picker")
```